# On a counterexample (Remark 14.8) - The Joy of Cats

Tags: category-theory

In "The Joy of Cats" (pag. 242-243) the authors show the equivalence between the fact that a category ${\bf A}$ is $(E,M)$-structured and three conditions, namely that isomorphisms are contained in $E \cap M$, that $E$ and $M$ are stable under composition and the unique $(E,M)$-factorization property.

After the proof, the authors give the following remark: if the $(E,M)$-factorization property is not unique (i.e. there are at least two isomorphisms making commutative the diagram induced by two $(E,M)$-factorizations of a morphism $f$), then the $(E,M)$-factorizations are not unique. To see this, they take a category with three objects $A,B,C$ and four non-identity morphisms $e: A \to B$, $m: B \to C$, $f: A \to C$ and $h: B \to B$ be such that $h \circ h=h$. If $E=Iso({\bf A}) \cup \{e\}$ and $M=Iso({\bf A}) \cup \{m\}$, then both $h$ and $Id_B$ serve as diagonals.

Please, see http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf pag. 242-244, for detailes.

Such an example seems very strange. In fact, I expect $h$ to be an isomorphism. But this would imply $h=Id_B$, after composing with $h^{-1}$. So why the uniqueness of the isomorphism does not hold in such a case?

Comment: Is something missing from the sentence where you give the authors' remark? You start with "If the factorization property is not unique" and then you have the parentheses, but the sentence doesn't seem to be finished off.

Comment: It looks like the "following remark" is truncated somehow.  The opening "if..." is not matched to a conclusion: "then (1)–(3) would not imply that (E, M)-
factorizations are unique."

Comment: Now that I've followed the link to see that section of the book, it seems your problem statement is more garbled than merely missing a conclusion.  In fact the conclusion is about $(E,M)$-factorizations not being unique, while the "weakened" premise (3) involves $h$ not being unique.

Comment: Exactly. In the authors' assumptions, the isomorphism $h$ is not unique. As you can see, $Id_B$ and $h$ (assuming $h$ to be an isomorphism, otherwise it makes no sense) are two different diagonals for the factorization $f=m \circ e=m \circ e$. Well, first objection: if $h$ is an idempotent isomorphism, then it must agree with $Id_B$. Secondly, I do not see how an arrow admits two different factorizations, since $m \circ e=m \circ e$ is the same factorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the condition should be $h \circ h = id_B$, $h \circ e = e$ and $m \circ e = m$. In this case, $h$ and $id_B$ can indeed serve as diagonals.

Concrete example in the category of abelian groups:
$$
\Bbb Z \xrightarrow{e} {\Bbb Z} \times {\Bbb Z} \xrightarrow{h} {\Bbb Z} \times {\Bbb Z}\xrightarrow{m} {\Bbb Z}
$$
with $e(x) = (x, x)$, $h(x,y) = (y,x)$ and $m(x,y) = x+y$.

Comment: So, do you think there is some error in the book? And moreover, in this case, they want to say that $e=h \circ e$ and $e=Id_B \circ e$ are two different $(E,M)$-factorizations for $e$ which are not isomorphic, is it true?

Comment: Well, that's my guess, but I might be wrong.